# How should i refresh my AutoCompleteTextView component?

Tags: java, android, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using this block of code:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Cidade cidade = (Cidade) arg0.getSelectedItem();
                List<Bairro> bairros = RachandoTaxiController.getInstancia().getBairros(cidade);
                myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.completeOrigem);
                myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Bairro>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, bairros));

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

There i have a Spinner and when i select an Item, i should set my AutoCompleteTextView (from holoeverywhere) based on user choice of Spinner.
If i do it statically, it works. My autocompletetextview answer as expected. But when i put it into onItemSelected, my autocompletetextview still like edittext.... Nothing happens...
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put

```
myAutoCompl = (AutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.completeOrigem);
myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

these lines outside of **OnItemClickListener**.
Whenever you click on item, new instance of View from findViewById() is returned. Same for TextChangedListener. So try to put lines outside probably the best choice will be **onCreate()** method and it should works.